# CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE, temp_buffers and Postgres performance

Tags: postgresql, temporary-tables

I have a bunch of queries that use temporary tables, and most of them are working really good, but from time to time they take an usual amount of time: 3-5 seconds.

My `temp_buffers` is set to the default 8Mb and I'm thinking that maybe the problem is caused by the buffer being swapped to the disk when it overflows or something like that.

Is there a way of checking how much of the buffer is taken? Is my way of thinking at all reasonable? Maybe the allocation of new space is really fast and I should look at other places?

Comment: Check http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT - you may want to set `log_temp_files` to something useful (probably 0 for the first try).  Then check the PostgreSQL log for entries about temp files.